# How to add default value for nvarchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to make default value for a nvarchar column as a new GUID in SQL Server. But When I am trying to insert null value its still getting inserted as null and not a new GUID. Can someone please help.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use an `nvarchar` to store a GUID? Why not use a `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: Also, a `DEFAULT` value is for when a value is **excluded** from the `INSERT` or the `DEFAULT` is explicitly requested, *not* when `NULL` is passed to it. `INSERT INTO dbo.T (I,C) VALUES (1,NULL);` will insert the value `NULL` into the column `C`, even if it has a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` defined. Either omit the column or be explicit and say you want the `DEFAULT`: `INSERT INTO dbo.T(I) VALUES (2); INSERT INTO dbo.T (I,C) VALUES (3,DEFAULT);`

Comment: And `Allow Nulls` is Yes, so why should SQL server not insert a NULL, when you allow that?

Comment: We just don't want null values in column and values should be unique. Column can have nvarchars. A third party  job is inserting data in our DB and we can not exclude when NULL is passed

Comment: *"We just don't want null values in column"* Then why is it defined as an `nvarchar(50) NULL` rather than an `nvarchar(50) NOT NULL`? It also sounds like it should be *two* columns; an `nvarchar` is *not* the correct data type for a GUID value (as I stated in my initial comment) (and perhaps there should be a `CONSTRAINT` to ensure that either the `uniqueidentifier` or `nvarchar` column values isn't `NULL`).

Comment: Even if you change the table to disallow nulls, the import process is still going to try and insert null. Personally, I would leave it as it it, accept nulls in that column, and use another column for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks @Daid, Larnu Looks like i need to change my DB design a little bit, Thanks for help.

Comment: you need to set allow-nulls to false